# Wordpress plugins function code

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to make a simple plugin that displays some info in the users profile page ( I have managed this part) but what I am not getting to work is I want to add a function that will check to see if a file exists on in a folder ( I can do this part ) but when I add a function into the plugin code it does not work or stops the page from showing up.

Any help would be great I just need to trigger the function on load of user looking at there profile.

```
function check_file(){
  if($file == 'me.jpg'){
     //do something
  }
  else{}
}
 check_file();
```

Comment: Found the answer add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'check_file' );

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'check_file' );
```

Above line will run the `check_file` function when user will see the profile.

Comment: Now my function runs but does not actually see a file that is on a server the path is right .. :-( ..

Comment: function check_file() {
    
      $filename = 'http://www.website.com/pdf/test.pdf';
              if (file_exists($filename)) 
     {
                 echo 'The file '.$filename.' exists on server';
              } 
     else 
     {
                echo "The file ". $filename ." does not exist on server";
              }
    
    }